# AWS KCL C# not processing records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kcl

So I am new to AWS Kinesis, and I have a basis producer working just fine with using my default profile which has my IAM user details in the store.

I can see that the producer send messages to the single stream shard. That's all good.

I know there is a Kinesis Data Stream API consumer that also uses the AmazonKinesisClient. But I read the preferred approach was to use the KCL library

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-net

So I downloaded the sample consumer from the link above, and did the following

1. Made sure I had environment variables for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY for the SampleConsumer app
2. Made sure I had Java installed
3. Edited the SampleConsumer command line args to include "--properties kcl.properties --execute"
4. Made sure the kcl.properties file has the correct streamName/executableName/regionName (which I changed to match my region for producer/my AWS account, so eu-west-2)

Then when I run the SampleConsumer from above with the SampleProducer, all I see for the SampleConsumer is a blank console application.

The producer is 100% fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In additon to the above I have also run the boostrapper to obtain the relevant KCL MultiLanuage JAR files

Comment: Did you find any solution about this? Currently I have the same issue (the stream name in kcl.properties have been updated with the proper name)

Comment: Yeah its to with path in config file. Has to be full path. I wrote about it at sachabarber.net (my blog)